# Convert from string to Datetime T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to retrieve specific month using date-time field let's say that i have following table

```
ID - DATETIME - AMOUNT
01 - 27/05/2017 - 1
02- 02/06/2017 - 2
03- 03/07/2017 - 1
04- 05/05/2017 - 2
05- 13/06/2017 - 3
```

What is the proper way to write a query to retrieve the records of May only
I have used the following query but it gave me error.

> SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.DATETIME = '05/2017'

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: Is `DATETIME` a `DATE` or a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: It's a datetime or a date. If it was a varchar you would not get a conversion error.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this (but if you have an index on the `TABLE.DATETIME` column, it will not be used):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE 
WHERE  MONTH(TABLE.DATETIME) = 5
   AND YEAR(TABLE.DATETIME) = 2017
```

It may be more efficient (if you have or have plans to add an index) to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE 
WHERE  TABLE.DATETIME >= '20170501'
   AND TABLE.DATETIME < '20170601'
```

Comment: @Nawaf you don't want to use the version that uses functions on the column. It will prevent you from ever use an index to locate the rows you need.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson could you please elaborate more?

Comment: What @MikaelEriksson (and myself) meant, was that if you query an attribute in a function (`year()`, `sum()`, `convert()` etc etc) sql server is not able to use an index on that attribute. So if you *do* have an index on that attribute, the query without functions will be significantly faster that a query with functions.

Answer (score 2):

Check against the start and end of month.

```
where DateTime >= '20170501' and
      DateTime < '20170601'
```

Comment: This is the best answer, right here from a performance perspective and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use between clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE 
WHERE TABLE.DATETIME BETWEEN '01/05/2017' AND '31/05/2017'
```

Comment: Only if the column DateTime is of type date. If it is a `datetime` you will not get the rows with a value of `20170531` where the time part is greater than `00:00`.